# No puedo obtener el Uri en algunos dispositivos

Tags: android, bitmap

acabo de migrar mi código de sdk 22 a sdk 23, y en el celular de prueba (moto g3) no tuve problemas, pero resulta que hay dispositivos que presentan problemas (Samsung Galaxy J2)...
Antes cuando usaba compileSdkVersion = 22, ambos teléfonos funcionaban, pero ahora que uso 23, el samsung se cae...

A nivel de código trato de obtener un getPath de un Bitmap.

Primero obtengo el getUri del bitmap, para luego utilizarlo y obtener el getPath, de la siguiente manera:

```
Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) mImagenView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bm);    //aca se caé
```

...

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    if(verificarPermisoAlmacenamiento()) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);    //especificamente aqui
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
}
```

acá path es null... en el samsung.

¿se debe a algun cambio en la libreria C:.....\Android\sdk\sources\android-23\android\provider?

TODA ayuda es bien recibida...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es al obtener el path de la imagen:

```
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
```

Si revisamos la documentación encontramos que:

> **[insertImage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html)** Puede retornar null si la imagen tuvo un problema al ser
>   almacenada.

Primeramente asegura tener el permiso:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Recuerda que si tu dispositivo usa Android 6.0 se deben requerir **[permisos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous)**, esto también puede ser una causa por la cual obtienes un valor `null`.

Puedes agregar este segmento de código para requerir permisos en dispositivos android 6.0

```
 int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para escribir.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso!");
    }
```

Comment: Si verifico el permiso, solo que esta siendo llamado con... verificarPermisoAlmacenamiento() trae verdadero si el permiso esta permitido y sé que es verdadero porque se caé adentro de este if

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado!

Como no podia usar GetImageUri() estuve buscando y resulta que el Uri se obtiene del Intent

[respuesta correcta aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10230234/4959545)

Comment: "El Uri se obtiene del Intent", no entiendo a que te refieres. Si enviaste el valor mediante startActivityForResult() creo que falto documentarlo en tu pregunta.